# iam getting buffer and hex codes

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readFile('TestFile.txt', function (err, data) {
                    if (err) throw err;

    console.log(data);
});
```

`//TestFile.txt This is test file to test fs module of Node.js`

1. Iam getting buffer and hex codes in place of console data
2. <Buffer 54 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 74 65 73 74 20 66 69 6c 65 20 74 6f 20 74 65 73 74 20 66 73 20 6d 6f 64 75 6c 65 20 6f 66 20 4e 6f 64 65 2e 6a 73>

Comment: Not sure what the question is! I guess you want to see text from the file.

Answer (score 0):

According to [the documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#filehandlereadfileoptions) :

> If no encoding is specified (using options.encoding), the data is returned as a `<Buffer>` object. Otherwise, the data will be a string.

Solution : add an encoding (and read the doc! :)

```
fs.readFile('TestFile.txt', { encoding : 'utf8' } , function()...
```

Answer (score 0):

By converting data to String(data) you will get text